# Teamcity Duplicates finder (.NET) fails with exception JetBrains.Application.Progress.ProcessCancelledException

Tags: duplicates, resharper, teamcity

My **TeamCity** (8.1.1 (build 29939)) fails when running **Duplicates Finder (.NET)**

Exception name is: **JetBrains.Application.Progress.ProcessCancelledException**

It seems to be running Resharper inside which had this issue in the past, see this bug report: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-270020

Any ideas how to fix this in TeamCity?

Log:

```
[13:43:52][Step 1/1] 191 files found to analyse.
[13:43:58][Step 1/1] Duplicates report was writen to C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\dupfinder-report-6469281220803475163.xml
[13:43:58][Step 1/1] Total time: 00:00:28.1269803
[13:43:58][Step 1/1] User time: 00:00:26.3173687
[13:43:58][Step 1/1] Peak virtual memory: 809MB
[13:43:58][Step 1/1] Peak working set: 288MB
[13:43:59]
[Step 1/1] Internal exception thrown: Exception of type 'JetBrains.Application.Progress.ProcessCancelledException' was thrown.

--- EXCEPTION #1/2 [ProcessCancelledException]
ExceptionPath = Root.InnerException
ClassName = JetBrains.Application.Progress.ProcessCancelledException
HResult = COR_E_EXCEPTION=80131500
Source = JetBrains.Platform.ReSharper.Shell
StackTraceString = "
  at JetBrains.Application.TryReadLockCookie.Create(IProgressIndicator progress, IShellLocks shellLocks, Func`1 checkForInterruptAction, Boolean releaseOnlyWhenLockHeld)
     at JetBrains.ReSharper.Psi.Util.Caches.SimplePersistentCache`1.Load(IProgressIndicator progressIndicator, IPersistentIndexManager persistentIdIndex, Func`3 readData, Action`2 dataLoaded)
     at JetBrains.ReSharper.Psi.GeneratedCode.GeneratedFilesCache.JetBrains.ReSharper.Psi.Caches.ICache.Load(IProgressIndicator progress, Boolean enablePersistence)
     at JetBrains.ReSharper.Psi.Caches.Jobs.JobLoadCache.Do(IProgressIndicator progress, Boolean sync, Func`1 checkForTermination)
"

--- Outer ---

--- EXCEPTION #2/2 [LoggerException]
Message = "Exception of type 'JetBrains.Application.Progress.ProcessCancelledException' was thrown."
ExceptionPath = Root
ClassName = JetBrains.Util.LoggerException
InnerException = "Exception #1 at Root.InnerException"
HResult = COR_E_APPLICATION=80131600
StackTraceString = "
  at JetBrains.ReSharper.Psi.Caches.Jobs.JobLoadCache.Do(IProgressIndicator progress, Boolean sync, Func`1 checkForTermination)
     at JetBrains.ReSharper.Psi.Caches.Jobs.CacheJobService2.DoJobWithLogging(Job job, IProgressIndicator progress, Boolean sync)
     at JetBrains.ReSharper.Psi.Caches.Jobs.CacheJobService2.<>c__DisplayClass5.<EnqueueJob>b__3()
     at JetBrains.Application.Threading.Tasks.TaskHost.<>c__DisplayClass11.<Create>b__e(Object state)
     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)
     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(Boolean bPreventDoubleExecution)
     at JetBrains.Application.Threading.Tasks.JetScheduler.JetSchedulerThread.ThreadPoolProc()
     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
     at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade to the latest TeamCity 8.1.3 solved the problem.